# openconnect on startup at debian wheezy through ssh

Tags: vpn, cisco, openconnect

I am trying to connect to Cisco vpn using open connect.

I can do it with the terminal where it asks for my user and pass.

However, is there any method for automating this on login.

Answer (score 1):

Set up PKI based authentication. ssh-keygen on the client, ssh-copy-id user@host, enter your password and then attempt to log in without using your password after by doing ssh user@host.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260/how-do-i-setup-public-key-authentication